# Struts 2 - Select default value

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, ognl

I had two select like this :

```
<s:select label = "Pays " list="payss" key="pays" value="%{FRANCE}"></s:select>
<s:select label = "Categorie " list="categories" key="categorie" value="%{200}">/s:select>
```

The second default value works but the first is not, the lists are like this :

**`payss`:**

1. FRANCE
2. BELGIQUE

**`categories`:**

1. 200
2. 300

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
value="%{'FRANCE'}"
```

OGNL is looking for the variable FRANCE and couldn't find it, because you didn't use it in the `valueStack`.